# Complex condition with chained joins

Tags: r

I need to update a dataframe based on values in two other dataframes joined in a chain with the first one.

The target df `t_offices` has 4 fields of interest here:

```
       administrative_area_level_1 administrative_area_level_2       country     locality
     1                     Arizona             Maricopa County United States      Phoenix
     2        District of Columbia                        <NA> United States   Washington
     3                        <NA>                        <NA>         India         <NA>
     4                    New York               Albany County United States       Albany
     5                     Utrecht                  Nieuwegein   Netherlands   Nieuwegein
     6                 Connecticut            Fairfield County United States     Stamford
   707                    Illinois                        <NA> United States         <NA>
  4241                    Illinois                        <NA> United States West Chicago
999998                     Alabama                        <NA> United States      Altoona
999999                Pennsylvania                        <NA> United States   Washington
```

I need to update NA values in `administrative_area_level_2` with a county for U.S. records. The values are in df `t_places`:

```
      state_ab           place_name                  county_name place_nameshort
     1      AL           Abanda CDP              Chambers County          Abanda
     2      AL       Abbeville city                 Henry County       Abbeville
     3      AL      Adamsville city             Jefferson County      Adamsville
     4      AL         Addison town               Winston County         Addison 
     5      AL           Akron town                  Hale County           Akron
     6      AL       Alabaster city                Shelby County       Alabaster
    12      AL         Altoona town Blount County, Etowah County         Altoona
  4298      DC      Washington city         District of Columbia      Washington
  7527      IL    West Chicago city                DuPage County      Washington
 32611      PA  Washington township             Armstrong County    West Chicago
 32612      PA  Washington township                 Berks County      Washington
```

`place_nameshort` is a truncated version of `place_name` without designation (e.g. "city", "town", etc.)

I join `t_offices` and `t_places` on states and places in order to get the right county. This may return multiple counties 1) because `county_name` can contain multiple counties separated by a comma, and 2) because truncated `place_nameshort` may return synonyms within the same state. I need **just those cases where the county is unambiguous** (single county returned).

Since `t_places` contains only `state_ab`, I need a third dataframe `r_states` for `state_name`:

```
   state_ab             state_name
 1       AL                Alabama
 2       AK                 Alaska
 3       AZ                Arizona
 4       AR               Arkansas
 5       CA             California
 6       CO               Colorado
 9       DC   District of Columbia
17       IL               Illinois
42       PA           Pennsylvania
```

By joining `t_places` with `r_states` on `state_ab`, I can get `state_name` matched with `t_offices$administrative_area_level_1`.

This my attempt, which is incomplete since it does not control for multiple counties due to in-state synonyms, and which doesn't work anyway.

```
no_county <- (!is.na(t_offices$country) 
          & t_offices$country == "United States" 
          & !is.na(t_offices$administrative_area_level_1) 
          & is.na(t_offices$administrative_area_level_2) 
          & !is.na(t_offices$locality))

t_offices$administrative_area_level_2[no_county] <-
  t_places$county_name[!grepl(",", t_places$county_name) 
                       & match(t_places$place_nameshort, t_offices$locality[no_county]) 
                       & match(t_places$state_ab, 
                               r_states$state_ab[match(r_states$state_name, 
                                                       t_offices$administrative_area_level_1[no_county])])]
```

EDIT: Following @r2evans' advice, here's my new coding attempt, which still doesn't work:

```
# split multiple counties into columns
library(splitstackshape)
t_places <- cSplit(t_places, "county_name", sep = ", ", drop = F, type.convert = F)

# merge state names into places  
places_statename <- merge(t_places, r_states[,2:3])

# define condition to select t_offices records in U.S. with state and place but no county
no_county <- (
  # country is U.S.
  !is.na(t_offices$country)
  & t_offices$country == "United States"
  # with state
  & !is.na(t_offices$administrative_area_level_1)
  # blank county
  & is.na(t_offices$administrative_area_level_2)
  # with place
  & !is.na(t_offices$locality))

# update blank counties
t_offices$administrative_area_level_2[no_county] <-
  # unambiguous counties
  places_statename$county_name_1[is.na(places_statename$county_name_2)
                                 # locality matches place
                                 & match(t_offices$locality[no_county], places_statename$place_nameshort)
                                 # administrative_area_level_1 matches state
                                 & match(t_offices$administrative_area_level_1[no_county],places_statename$state_name)]
```

Comment: I suggest you reform your data in order to support direct joining (via `merge` or `dplyr::left_join` and friends). This makes everything considerably easier, more robust, and a lot easier to work with/troubleshoot. A start: if `county_name` can contain multiple comma-separated values, split them with something like `tidyr::separate` and then `tidyr::gather` (so that joining is more intuitive/easy. Second suggestion: please make this question reproducible; as it stands, we don't have representative data that meets all of your requirements.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for your suggestions! I've added (real and made-up) sample data to make the question reproducible. As for your first suggestion, should I merge t_places and r_states and melt county_name into a single table and then join that table with t_offices?

Comment: @r2evans not melt, but transpose into multiple columns

Comment: "Reproducible" here implies "easy to use on my own laptop". This suggests not having to type it in manually. It would help if you provided the output of `dput` on the data subsets you've provided.

Comment: @r2evans I've dput r_states, t_places and a sample of t_offices (all missing county -- there are records which don't) [here](http://www.filedropper.com/socomquestions41929390sampledput).

Comment: Following @r2evans' advice, here's my new [coding attempt](http://pastebin.com/SLZCks3x), which still doesn't work.

Comment: If you can avoid it, please keep edits and sample data within this page: it will become completely useless if and when those two links you posted expire for any reason; by putting your `dput` data and code changes as edits to the question on this page, you keep it all self-contained (and ideally completely representative and reproducible).

Comment: @r2evans I've put the new code in the OP, but I'm afraid my sample data is too voluminous to paste here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my long solution. There are probably shorter, more elegant ones.

```
# split multiple counties into columns
library(splitstackshape)
t_places <- cSplit(t_places, "county_name", sep = ", ", drop = F, type.convert = F)
# subset original places with single county
places_singlecounty <- t_places[is.na(places_statename$county_name_2), c(1,8,9)]
# subset truncated places with single county
library(data.table)
setDT(places_singlecounty)
places_singlecounty <- merge(places_singlecounty, 
                             places_singlecounty[, .N, by = c("state_ab", "place_nameshort")][N == 1, 1:2])
# merge state names into single-county truncated places
places_statename <- merge(places_singlecounty, r_states[,2:3], by = "state_ab")

# define condition to select t_offices records in U.S. with state and place but no county
no_county <- (
  # country is U.S.
  !is.na(t_offices$country) 
  & t_offices$country == "United States" 
  # with state
  & !is.na(t_offices$administrative_area_level_1) 
  # NA county
  & is.na(t_offices$administrative_area_level_2) 
  # with place
  & !is.na(t_offices$locality))

# update t_offices NA counties based on single-county truncated places
setDT(t_offices)
t_offices[no_county, administrative_area_level_2 := 
           places_statename[.(.SD), county_name_1,
                            on = c(state_name = "administrative_area_level_1",  
                                   place_nameshort = "locality")]]
```